# How to change the background color of rows in a datagridview with a condition when the form loads

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am having trouble with manipulating the datagridview. My problem is I want to change the color of the background color of rows to red where Status (A field in my database, number 20 in the array) is equal to "Inactive" and the "Active" ones gets green when the form loads.

Comment: Please post your (relevant) code! That way people can help easier :)

Comment: Is [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=vb+.net+datagridview+row+color) broken today?

Comment: well i have been searching for a while can't get the correct term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of doing it in **C#**, you will have to adapt it to your specific case :

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (YourDataSourceAsList[e.RowIndex].GetStatus() == "Inactive")
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    else
        ...
}
```